# SharePoint online column formatting JSON - replace @currentfield

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm currently using SharePoint column formatting JSON to turn a field's string entry into a text, based on it's value.

For instance:

1. whenever @currentfield is equal to number 10, it should replace the number 10 with "Hello"
2. whenever @currentfield is equal to number 20, it should replace the number 20 with "Bye",
3. Otherwise do nothing.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use below JSON for you column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == 10, 'Hello', if(@currentField == 20, 'Bye', ''))"
}
```

**Output**:

Before applying JSON:

[image]

After applying JSON:

[image]

---

If you want to keep @currentField value as it is for 3rd condition, use:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == 10, 'Hello', if(@currentField == 20, 'Bye', @currentField))"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sarmad, does this answer your question?